# Gmail calendar do not receive answer from iCloud calendar

Tags: iphone, icloud, calendar, gmail, ical

**Problem:** I do not see whether an iCloud user accepted/declined my invitation which I created in Gmail Calendar.

**My steps**:

1. I create a new event in Gmail Calendar. Add them user with  iCloud email wich use iCloud Calendar.
2. iCloud user receives invitation, which he accepts.

I **expected** that iCloud send an `*.ics` file to Gmail with this answer.
But **actually** Gmail calendar does not show whether the iCloud user accept this invitation.

Comment: Has your process ever worked ?

Comment: For iPhone\icloud never worked. I have checked on several different devices\accounts